# read image data from web page to a firefox addon insecure?

Tags: firefox, canvas, plugins

I'm currently doing a plugin on firefox, which should be very simple. But since I am new on that, some problems have occured:

The purpose is to bind an item on the context menu when user clicking on an image(). I want to manipulate this image a lot(some work like visual encryption) using a canvas, and display the result in a new panel or dialog.

To bind the new item onto the menu, following code is used.

```
cm.Item({
    label: _("menu-label-encrypt"),
    context: cm.SelectorContext("img"),
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url('jquery.js'),
        data.url('encrypt.menu.js'),
    ],
    onMessage: function(cmd){
        var cryptWorker = imgcrypt();
        cryptWorker.key(cmd.password);
        var ret = cryptWorker.encrypt( cmd.width, cmd.height, cmd.data);
        console.log(ret.length);
    },
});
```

My idea is to use the contextScriptFile `encrypt.menu.js` to inject a code into the page, and fetch the canvas data as an array, which will then be posted using `self.postMessage` to the addon and get processed:

```
self.on('click', function(node){
    var canvasID = 'cache';
    var img = $(node)[0];
    $('<canvas>', {id: canvasID}).appendTo('body').hide();

    var canvas = $('#' + canvasID)[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data,
        dataAry = new Array(data.length);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        dataAry[i] = data[i];

    var command = {
        'password': 'test',
        'width': img.width,
        'height': img.height,
        'data': dataAry,
    };

    self.postMessage(command);
});
```

and now the problem came to my surprise: when I tried this addon on some page hosted at `localhost:4000`, it works. On some real web page, it shows:

```
menu.js:14 - SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

I **know** that this may be caused by a violation of some same-origin policy, but this is a content-script injected by an addon. Is it also impossible to read the image data without some help of a external server, or am I doing something totally wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found any solution to this approach(that being said, to inject a content to get the data from an remotely retrived image). But the `net/xhr` in mozilla's sdk works at the side of addon well. Alternatively I have wrote a XHR working in `main.js` and used it as a proxy.

At the side of addon, this `XMLHttpRequest` have no same-domain restrictions and can be used to retrive the binary data of the image given by a URL. The retrived data can be returned in a form of `ArrayBuffer` by setting `xhr.responseType='arraybuffer';`

The URL given to the addon's XHR is simply the src of `<IMG>`, which is being clicked. The browser seems to be caching the image and using XHR to retrive this image is very fast and doesn't need another request to the server.